# Extracting common code from Xamarin Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been writing a Xamarin Android app and am now in a position where I have a load of generic business logic (including SQLite.Net stuff). I would like to move this to a separate project, in case I decide to have a go at a Xamarin iOS project. Can this just be a vanilla class library project or is there more to it?

This business logic code contains some strings that will need localizing. I guess the only option will be to store them in a resx resource file in the new project?

Comment: if you want to share it with iOS, it will need to be either a PCL or a Shared Library

Comment: Here are your options: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/

Answer (score 0):

For the project itself you can use a PCL, this is in fact my favorite option of sharing code between projects in a Xamarin solution or you can go with Shared Projects which I don't like it very much but many people use it and it works. Here's the [link](https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/) I always use as reference when asked which one to use so you can decide yourself based on the pros and cons of each one.

About the localization you can definitely use a resx resource file but you will need to implement your own localization service to read from the files.